# How do I improve ecological conditions?

Tags: anno-2070

I have an "eco balance" of -45, and it's saying that I have acid soil and stuff like that. I've looked through my buildings and all I find are buildings that are negative or neutral, nothing that improves things.

Am I just supposed to accept things being bad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few buildings that increase the eco balance.

For the Eco faction:

```
Weather Control System:         +15 (+300)
Monitoring Station:             +40 (+300)
Ozone Maker Station:            +100 (+300)
River Sewage Treatment Plant:   +300
```

For the Tycoon Faction:

```
Waste Compactor:                +50 (+200)
Deacidification Station:        +90 (+200)
CO2 Reservoir:                  +200
```

[Source](http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/Eco_balance)